# How to access nested StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using interactive data display lib, and I want to generate my charts dynamically. Unfortunatelly I can't access one of the StackPanels by its name:

```
<Grid>
    <d3:Chart Name="plotter">
        <d3:Chart.Title>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Margin="0,5,0,5">Line graph legend sample</TextBlock>
        </d3:Chart.Title>
        <d3:Chart.LegendContent>
            <d3:LegendItemsPanel>
                <d3:LegendItemsPanel.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="InteractiveDataDisplay.WPF.LineGraph">
                        <StackPanel Name="chartPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </d3:LegendItemsPanel.Resources>
            </d3:LegendItemsPanel>
        </d3:Chart.LegendContent>
        <Grid Name="lines"/>
    </d3:Chart>
</Grid>
```

And when I am trying to access it by name (chartPanel.method()) it seems that it doesnt exist.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve here. chartPanel is not a single element in the visual tree of your application. Instead it is an element in a DataTemplate, hence there may be multiple instances.

Comment: Hmm, so I misunderstand how it works. I actually managed to create graph, but I want to achive legend of its. 
In StackPanel there were UI elements like checkboxes and lines which for each function represented legend.
So it works like:
For each LineGraph element in Chart named plotter it creates StackPanel with legend? Am I wrong?

Comment: Okay thanks for response, it helped me to understand how it works just by your mentioning "hence there may be multiple instances.". It gave me a lot of thinking I looked into the xaml code once more and noticed taht it is doing all work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this in your Code

```
  private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null) return null;

            if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return child;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not found it - search children
                DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                if (nextLevel != null)
                    return nextLevel;
            }
        }
        return null;
```

After that u can search the stackpanel with this Method:

```
 StackPanel chartPanel= FindChildControl<StackPanel>(plotter, "chartPanel") as StackPanel;
```

now you can edit your Stackpanel.

Comment: Actually it is an answer to my question, but Clemens made me realize that it is not I might looking for. Thank you very much anyway!